# convert comma delimited listbox items to XML file

Tags: .net, xml, wpf, listbox

I need code that adds employee data from text box to List item with comma delimited for Display purpose.
Now when submit button gets pressed it takes list of employee from listbox and write it out in XML format. 
Can anyone help me out with it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using MVVM approach to implement this. Have the details (name, age etc) fields bind to string properties in the ViewModel, then make Add Employee button use `Command` binding. The command should add the employee into an `ObservableCollection<Employee>`, whereas you would need to have an `Employee` model class. If you still insist on having comma-separated strings to display those employees, then you can let the listbox do a `MultiBinding` to the `ObservableCollection<Employee>`, and set a `IMultiValueConverter`.

For serialization to XML, you can simply make the `Employee` class implement `ISerializable`, and serialize that collection of employees back to XML using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` class.

It is hard to explain everything here, if you are interested in using MVVM, you should google for it and start reading on it.